# How to drop rows if tow conditions replicate has zero?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have data like two conditions (condition 1, condition 2) and each conditions with six replicates. I would like to drop if condition 1's three out of two replicate has zero in row (sample/row).

```
gene_name   con1_1 con1_2 con1_3 con2_1 con2_2  con2_3
YLZC_aa4043 251.0000    233    116     61     79  73.000
YLZC_aa4046   0           0      1      1      1  53.000
YLZC_aa4048  26.0133    232.296  0      0      232.296
YLZC_aa4050   0           0      0     36     20   0.000
```

I expect output like this

```
gene_name    con1_1   con1_2 con1_3 con2_1 con2_2  con2_3
YLZC_aa4043 251.0000    233    116     61     79  73.000
YLZC_aa4048  26.0133    232.296  0      0      232.296
```

And i am relatively new to R

I know how to do it by one by one but i would like to do with dplyr. So i tried with dplyr. But could not finish i am kind of stuck. can someone please guide me

```
data %>% select(2:4) %>% select_if(rowSums == 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

As per you update, you can try

```
subset(df, rowSums(df[startsWith(names(df), "con1_")] == 0) <= 1)
```

---

Maybe this base R option using `rowSums` + `startsWith` can help

```
> subset(df, rowSums(df[startsWith(names(df), "con1_")] == 0) == 0)
    gene_name con1_1 con1_2 con1_3 con2_1 con2_2 con2_3
1 YLZC_aa4043    251    233    116     61     79     73
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I have a general question. Where can practice this stuff. Because the tutorials what i referred was kind of basic. I would like to get some hard core practise. So can you please suggest some data and practicals regarding data cleaning and data handling.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think Stack Overflow is the place you are looking for.

Comment: Great. But here i can come over to get a solution. I would like to practice. Any books or something..

Comment: @PraveenKumar I guess there are a lot online resources, you can find the one suits you best anyway.

Comment: But , i would like to drop three out of two condition 1's  column has zero. How can i implement on this. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter(rowSums(select(cur_data(), starts_with('con1')) != 0) > 1)
    gene_name con1_1 con1_2 con1_3 con2_1 con2_2 con2_3
1 YLZC_aa4043    251    233    116     61     79     73
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(gene_name = c("YLZC_aa4043", "YLZC_aa4046", "YLZC_aa4048", 
"YLZC_aa4050"), con1_1 = c(251, 0, 26.0133, 0), con1_2 = c(233L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), con1_3 = c(116L, 1L, 0L, 0L), con2_1 = c(61L, 1L, 
0L, 36L), con2_2 = c(79L, 1L, 0L, 20L), con2_3 = c(73, 53, 232.296, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Why the `starts_with("con2")`-part? If I'm right, condition 2 doesn't have any impact on the actual question: "_to drop if condition 1's three out of two_"

Comment: @MartinGal You are right.  I was thinking that it should be repeated. updated

Comment: My con2 is a control so i am selecting the row based on experiment. Not by other way around.